# Problems with offline apt-get package repository, file not found: Packages

Tags: apt, server, package-management, repository

I have two machines running Ubuntu 20.04 server. One of the them is offline as a cold machine and I have tried to set up a offline apt repository with deb files from my online server on it but no matter what I try I get this error:

```
E: Failed to fetch file:/tmp/repo/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages File not found
```

My /etc/apt/sources-list has thsi entry at the top of the file:

```
deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] file:///tmp/repo focal main
```

My directory structure on the offline machine is:

```
/tmp/repo/
   dist/focal/main/binary-amd64/
      Packages.gz
      Packages.xz
      Release
   pool/
      all *.deb files from online server (/var/cache/apt)
```

I am not sure why apd-update want the file "Packages" I have Packages.gz and .xz
I followed this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository (which btw omits any info on what to do with the .deb files)

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for a similar problem. Unfortunately you were just silently downvoted and left with no response. Hopefully some activity will at least illicit a link to an answer instead of the lazy cold shoulder.

Comment: This is a commentary not an answer. Please only provide the answer in the answer section.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230819)